# Automate Reporting TFS and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have to Automate the process of creating a reports in TFS+ Visual Studio

Following are the Steps

1. Open Data from TFS query in Excel (We have option to do so in VS 2012/2013)
2. Format the Date Column.

I am planning to make a web application to generate reports on a button click.

If I click a button Report 1. The following 2 steps should run and report should be generated. This is my idea.

I am not sure how to start. Is there any documentation available about this? How can I programmatically open the TFS Query in Excel?

Comment: I don't necessarily think this is the best approach to your problem.  Have you considered the reporting functionality of TFS? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb649552.aspx

Comment: I am still struggling with how to set up reporting features. Could someone help. I just want the reporting capabilities enabled in my TFS

Answer (score 0):

Have you look to the Reporting Features of TFS : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb649552.aspx ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  You mean the effective way to do this is to do it via TFS reporting? Right? Thank you even I was wondering about the different options

Comment: Yep I would build my Web Application to browse my different reports generated by SSRS. There is a Web.Forms control to display SSRS report available: https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa337091.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you're building a report, I'm assuming that you don't need the two-way data binding that the Visual Studio export provides.

I don't necessarily think it's the best way to do it, but you *could* connect to TFS programmatically, retrieve the work items via the work item query, and then use an Excel library to export that data to Excel:

```
     TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
          new Uri("http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
    WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tpc.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));

QueryHierarchy queryRoot = workItemStore.Projects[0].QueryHierarchy;
QueryFolder folder = (QueryFolder) queryRoot["Shared Queries"];
QueryDefinition query = (QueryDefinition)folder["Active Bugs"];
queryResults = workItemStore.Query(query.QueryText);
foreach(WorkItem wi in queryResults)
{

     // Export to Excel
}
```

I still think you're better off exploring some of the reporting services offered in TFS.